# order received from date to date correct sentence

Tags: time, dates

I was writing a line on a website of mine to inform users that starting from 11 o'clock of Aug 5th, through Aug 19th we won't be able to ship. Shipments will start again on Aug 22nd.

I wrote:

> Note: Order placed between 11 o'clock of Aug. 5th through Aug. 19th
>   will be shipped starting from Aug. 22nd

Is that form correct or? Should I use "through" to mark a whole period...until....?

I have the feeling it is completely messed 
Thank yo very much

Answer (score 1):

> Orders placed between 11PM/2300 on August 5, 2016 and 11PM/2300 on August 19 will be shipped on or after August 22, 2016.

Or some variation thereof.  I would use the time in both for consistency.

Comment: thank you very much. I've just realized that I should write Aug 21st, not 19th :) Thanks again